# Automatically add installed app icon to first screen with space

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, samsung-galaxy-note-5

I have 5 home screen pages in my Note 5.

When a new app is installed, its icon is added to the last page and not the first one, even though there is space in the first page.

Anyone know how to fix that so the shortcut will appear on the first page (or in the nearest page which has empty spots)?

Answer (score 0):

You have edited home pages of your launcher.
you can change sequence of ui that you will able to see apps on first screen